# Can I access winapi calls from an ActiveX control?

Tags: winapi, internet-explorer-11, activex

I know it's ActiveX and a security nightmare, but I'm curious if I could call WinAPI calls like SystemParametersInfo or MessageBox from an ActiveX control. MSDN doesn't have a lot about this (or I couldn't find it)

Comment: yes, you can call winapi of course. activex implemented in dll, which loaded in process. so you can, and dll anyway will be call some winapi. if browser run in low-level, sandbox process, some api call can return access denied for you. but call you can anyway. *MessageBox* exactly can

Comment: So in the end it depends on the privilege level of internet explorer? Or will the sandboxing prevent me from changing the wallpaper?

Comment: you can call any api from dlls loaded in process. another task that some api calls can fail. especially if this require write to registry or disk. if you call `SystemParametersInfo` from low integrity process, for change wallpaper - it fail with access denied. but call you can anyway

Comment: ActiveX control can call almost all the winapis. ActiveX controls is written in C or C++ and being compiled in Intel x86 Assembly language, making them executable only on Windows machines where they can call the standard Win32 APIs.